# How to get profile data from facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get profile data after authentication on facebook with nodejs.

I checked [facebook-passport code](https://github.com/passport-next/passport-facebook/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L60) how to construct url:

```
        const profileUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/3.1/me';
        var proof = crypto
            .createHmac('sha256', process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET)
            .update(result.access_token)
            .digest('hex');
        // url.search = (url.search ? url.search + '&' : '') + 'appsecret_proof=' + proof;

        const url = `${profileUrl}?appsecret_proof=${proof}`;
        console.log(url);
```

And the url is correct (for example - https://graph.facebook.com/3.1/me?appsecret_proof=e10a9d42c695bc80b5ca6aae17d4c4c0aadb633c5727cde7cec5e42d8e20d074 , but as you can see there is an error

```
"error": {
  "message": "Unknown path components: /me",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 2500,
  "fbtrace_id": "BO4/OUwq9lX"
}
```

Where am I wrong?

I noticed that it's possible to use facebook user id, but how can I get it. I can get only access_token or something like that, I don't have user id.

Comment: You need to pass the access token in the URL.

Comment: I don't think so. That algo generated `appsecret_proof ` from data including `access_token`, which I'm getting before by another request.

Comment: wizkid is right. appsecret_proof is just there for additional security, you must add the access_token.

Comment: I passed both, but the same issue.

Comment: You passed a user access token? That you got from the user login?

Comment: Yes, this is all code https://gist.github.com/zishe/47611a50daefb49a81f70663d3c36efd

Comment: Log the actual URL that the request is made to somewhere, and check what that contains.